# How do I add a new stylesheet to HTML but keep the old one in the line above? What is the tag to type for that?

Tags: html

How do i enable one stylesheet while keeping the code for the other one disabled?

Comment: Need more details. Like code you have done

Comment: <!-- CSS
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/shared/HTML Templates/Health/Health-CSS/theme-old.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="/content/dept/css/2019/themenew.css">

<script src="/content/schoolscripts/h5pResponsive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I know there is something i need to add before/after the old code so the page won't use it.

Comment: Even if I did understand this question (Which I totally don't), just keep a copy of the old css and change the path to the new file. Read [ask] and create a [mcve] (You can [edit] your question any time)

Comment: how do i keep a copy of the old css? i am very new to the language of HTML, but can rephrase as much as possible for clarity. Just ask.

Comment: how do i enable one stylesheet while keeping the code for the other one disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: form comment on the question: how to keep a reference to a style sheet but disabled:

There is no CSS way to disable a selector other than commenting it out (or editing to match no elements).

But a `<link>` element can be commented out in HTML:

```
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styling/somestyles.css"> -->
```

and the browser ignores the content of comments (with a few notable legacy exceptions).

---

*Original Answer*

An HTML document can include as many (or as few, including zero) stylesheets as it likes.

It does not matter if these are links to external stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styling/somestyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styling/morestyles.css">
```

or `<style>` blocks embedded in the HTML

```
<style type="text/css">
  h2 {
    color: green;
  }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
  h2.important {
    color: hotpink;
  }
</style>
```